TypeScript issue: P could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to Omit<Props<P>, 'Component'>
In my case, I have to pass components via props (eg. "title", "subTitle") and these props are optional. So instead of writing each time config.title ? renderTitle() : null, I'd like to have a component which will render nothing(null) or Component with props that was passed.
Example of usage:
import React from 'react';

type TitleProps = {
  title: string;
  id: number;
  name?: string;
  phone?: string;
};

type SubTitleProps = {
  title: string;
  id: number;
  name?: string;
  phone?: string;
};

type Props = {
  config: {
    title?: React.ComponentType<TitleProps>;
    subTitle?: React.ComponentType<SubTitleProps>;
  };
};

export const App: React.FC<Props> = ({ config }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <CustomComponent<TitleProps>
        Component={config.title}
        title="Title"
        id={12345}
        name="Nick"
      />
      <CustomComponent<SubTitleProps>
        Component={config.subTitle}
        title="Title"
        id={12345}
        name="Nick"
      />
    </>
  );
};

Below is the implementation of CustomComponent and type typescript error that I need to fix.
import React from 'react';

type Props<P> = P & {
  Component: React.FC<P>;
};

export const CustomComponent = <P = Record<string, any>,>({
  Component,
  ...rest
}: Props<P>) => {
  if (!Component) return null;

//TS Error below: TS2322: Type Omit<Props<P>, 'Component'> is not assignable to type IntrinsicAttributes & P
// Type Omit<Props<P>, 'Component'> is not assignable to type P
// P could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to Omit<Props<P>, 'Component'>
return <Component {...rest} />;
};


Any ideas?

why are you passing Component={SomeCompProps} ?

Hello. Yeah, you are right. In that example it is stupid to have an additional CustomComponent. So, I made changes to my example of usage - I pass {config: ...} from other places and title, subtitle are optional, maybe it has more sense in CustomComponent now.
